# Is there any way to remove an element from array in jsp?

Tags: java, arrays, spring, jsp

I want to give my users an ability to remove some items from database. Like this:

[image]

I have an array in jsp file:

```
<c:forEach items="${page.content}" var="row" varStatus="status">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
        <td>${row.name}</td>
        <td>${row.profession}</td>
        <td>${row.phone}</td>
        <td>${row.city.name}</td>
        <td><a href=""><img src="img/del.png"/></a></td>
```

Is there any way to remove an item from array "row" (for example, when I click on the picture del.png)? After that, I will send this array to the controller, to let it know which items I want to remove.

Comment: `forEach` loop is only for reading as you know, so...

Comment: probably you cannot remove thus you can write a if to filter as per condition.

Comment: @Neel, can you write a small example, please?

Answer (score 0):

So write a if condition inside foreach tag like this.My idea is to exclude or skip the creation of html if if condition is not satisfied with the value you will specify.

```
<c:forEach items="${page.content}" var="row" varStatus="status"> 
   <c:if test="${row.value != '<What you want to exclude>'}">
    <tr>   
    <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
    <td>${row.name}</td>
    <td>${row.phone}</td>
    <td>${row.city.name}</td>
    </tr>  
   </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: But, as I said, I need to send this row to controller with removed row. So the row has to be removed not only at screen, but from the array.

Comment: what is your array?row is simply a item of `page.content`?you can use jquery to trap the selected checkbox and do what you want.please edit your question clearly what you need and create http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm very sorry for this misunderstanding. My question was edit. Just look at the picture to understand what I want.